# WPF: Move control into new window

Tags: wpf

I have a control that placed into a custom panel. Into view model exist a boolean variable **IsStandAlone**. I wish when **IsStandAlone** is *true* that this control will be in new window.

I do this on setting **IsStandAlone** to *true*:

```
var window = new Window();
window.Content = this;
window.Closed += (s, ea) =>
{
     window.Content = null;
     ViewModel.IsStandAlone = false;
}
window.Show();
```

It's work good when i set **IsStandAlone** *true* but when i close the window control doesn't appear in the panel.

Comment: we could use a little more info about your custom control. Is it a window or a usercontrol. Do you want it in a new window or do you want it in a your current window? The answer to those questions will greatly affect the answer given

Comment: This is usercontrol that contains a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
...
If(IsStandAlone){ 
    var newWindow = new MyNewWindow();
    newWindow.Show();
}
...
```